# How to replace Open api spec in Azure Api Management service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a rest api with its specification written in OAS 3.x version.
This api spec yaml file has been uploaded into `Azure Api Management service`

Now I have added additional endpoints to this OpenAPI spec and I need to upload it again into `Azure Api Management service`

Now when I login to Azure >> API Management service >> I can see a list of api .
Next to my api ( whose spec I want to upload can see three dots )
[image]

When I click on it I get multiple options one being  :`import` IMport open api spec :
[image]

This is where I am confused .. which option should I be selecting ?
I simply need to update existing api specification with the new one ( with additional new endpoints )

I think I should be selecting `Update` but not quite sure ...

Comment: thanks but not sure I understood you , so should I not be using the ```update``` option ? also when you say do not replace I dont see any option to copy paste the api spec inside azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are facing issues with update, there is an alternate way. Go to your API and select 'All Operations' there you have an Open API specification editor. You can just replace your code there (copy/paste).

[image]